# Create new columns same as Column Values and merge it based on ID column in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

Business is creating a User form which tracks certain properties and associated values for an individual user session. The data is stored in the table in this form

```
data =[[100,"Prop1","Value1",False],[100,"Prop2","Value2",False],[200,"Prop1","Value3",False],[200,"Prop2","Value4",False],[200,"Prop3","Value5",True],[300,"Prop3","Value6",False],[300,"Prop4","Value7",False]]
columns = ["UserID","Property","Value","isDisabled"]
df_in = spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)
```

[Input Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y320O.png)

Each UserID will have a single row, with the Property name being a new Column with the associated Value in a map format. If the isDisabled column is False then the Property value is displayed or else it is displayed as blank

**Expected output**

[Output Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61L7w.png)

Appreciate any inputs on how this can be implemented. Thanks

Comment: For the User 100 you have only Prop1 & Prop2. But Expected output have 4 properties ?

Comment: @Roshan Yes. These properties are filled in based on the User preferences, so if User 100 didn't pick Prop3 or Prop4 it wouldn't show up any value. But for each User all the properties(Prop1,Prop2...PropN) in the input dataset should come across. The output is treated as the cumulative dataset for each User.

Answer (score 0):

[Result Show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVQkA.jpg)

```
(
  df_in
    .withColumn("add", when(col("isDisabled")==True, col("Value")).otherwise(lit("")))
    .withColumn("add", to_json(struct(col("add"))))
    .groupBy("UserID")
    .pivot("Property")
    .agg(first("add"))
.fillna('{"add":""}')
.sort("UserID")

    .withColumn("p1", get_json_object(col("Prop1"), "$.add"))
    .withColumn("p2", get_json_object(col("Prop2"), "$.add"))
    .withColumn("p3", get_json_object(col("Prop3"), "$.add"))
    .withColumn("p4", get_json_object(col("Prop4"), "$.add"))

    .show(10, False)  
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Lin. That worked. The one minor change I had to do was the when condition, when(col("isDisabled")==False.

Comment: Congratulations